# LINQ query check for unique object

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

I have the following data in a List object;

```
List<FailedMachines> lstObjects:
lstObjects[0] - Desc: Mach1    Name:Drill  Id: 1
lstObjects[1] - Desc: Mach1    Name:Crane  Id: 1
lstObjects[2] - Desc: Mach3    Name:Grader Id: 3
lstObjects[3] - Desc: Mach2    Name:Mixer  Id: 2
lstObjects[4] - Desc: Mach2    Name:Paver  Id: 2
lstObjects[5] - Desc: Mach4    Name:Lifts  Id: 4
lstObjects[6] - Desc: Mach4    Name:Forks  Id: 4
lstObjects[7] - Desc: Mach5    Name:Forks  Id: 5
```

I would like to retrieve only the `FailedMachines` that are unique and NOT in a pair. Id = 3 & 5 in this case.

```
lstObjects[2] - Desc: Mach3    Name:Grader Id: 3
lstObjects[2] - Desc: Mach5    Name:Grader Id: 5
```

**Note** that I'm using .Net Framework 4.8.

Comment: `list2.GroupBy(x => x.Desc).Where(g => g.Count() == 1).Select(g => g.First())` seems to work; https://dotnetfiddle.net/jHPhO2; Of course, that's grouping by `Desc`. If you were to group by `Name` it would be a different story...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I would think you would group by `Id`. Also, I think I would prefer `SelectMany(g => g)` instead of `Select(g => g.First())`.

Comment: @NetMage Sure. I didn't even look at the Id property, assuming it to be unique...